# How does storing JQuery Fields in an array compare to just storing the selection string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, memory-management, jquery-selectors

I am having to store a large array of JavaScriptobjects, these objects need to contain a message, and a way of selecting an associated HTML element.

Currently, I've been using the the following code to add to this array:

```
if (field[0].id != ""){
    this.selectorString = "#" + field[0].id;
}
else if (field.attr("name") != ""){
    this.selectorString = "[name='" + field.attr("name") + "']";
}
```

I didn't want to store the entire field, as I wasn't confident on JavaScripts/JQuery memory management or how it worked. Selection strings seemed the safer option, as opposed to a large array of fields. I could then just use the stored string to perform a JQuery selection statement and manipulate the field.

**The Big Question**

If I store the fields, will this take up a large amount of memory, or is it purely reference to an object that is already stored somewhere in the big black hole of JavaScript of which I know little?

Is there an alternative that anyone can think of that would enable me to achieve what I'm going for. The 'fields' can be divs/spans/input fields/anything, that might not necessarily have an ID/Name - which will cause problems if I'm not storing the field.

Many thanks.

Comment: you should use jq `.data()` method to store the datas you want, relative to specific jq object. That way, if element is removed, relevant datas are removed too, calling `jQuery.cleanData` internally  http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I store the fields, will this take up a large amount of memory, or is it purely reference to an object that is already stored somewhere in the big black hole of JavaScript of which I know little?

Just a reference (the "big black hole" is called the "DOM" or "DOM tree" or sometimes "page"). But note that if you *remove* the element you're referring to from the DOM at some point, but still have a reference to it from a JavaScript variable, the element is kept in memory (just not in the DOM tree) until/unless you assign a new value to that variable or that variable goes out of scope.

Concrete example: Say we have this on our page:

```
<div id="foo">....</div>
```

And we have this code:

```
var f = $("#foo");
```

Now we have a jQuery object wrapped around a reference to that element. It's not a *copy* of the element, just a reference to it.

Now suppose we did this:

```
f.remove();
```

That `div` is no longer in the DOM (on the page), but it still exists because we still have a reference to it from the `f` variable (indirectly; `f` refers to a jQuery object which, in turn, refers to the element). But if that variable goes out of scope, or we assign some other value to it (for instance, `f = null;`), then the element is not referenced from anywhere and can be reclaimed.

If you're not removing elements from the DOM (directly, or indirectly by replacing the contents of an an ancestor of theirs), then very little memory is used to simply refer to the existing element.

Comment: I see. Thank you, this has been very interesting and informative. Time for me to do some background reading!